# polar coordinates, finding tangents

Tags: polar-coordinates

I've been asked to find the coordinates of the points on the curve:

$r = acos2\theta, -\dfrac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{4}  $

where the tangents are parallel to the initial line.

The first thing I did was say:

$y = rsin\theta \space$ but $\space r = acos2\theta $ $\space \therefore \space y=acos2\theta sin\theta $

After rearranging, I got that:

$y = asin\theta (1 - 2sin^2\theta)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{d\theta} = acos\theta(1-2sin^2\theta) + asin\theta(-4sin\theta cos\theta)$

After rearranging this I found that:

$\dfrac{dy}{d\theta} = acos\theta(1-6sin^2\theta)$

So if I let:

$\dfrac{dy}{d\theta} = 0$

$\Rightarrow acos\theta(1-6sin^2\theta) = 0$

$\Rightarrow cos\theta = 0 \space$ or $\space sin\theta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$

If:

$cos\theta = 0 \Rightarrow \theta = \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

This is outside my range so I can ignore these values.

If:

$sin\theta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \Rightarrow \theta = 0.421 \space (3s.f.)$

I haven't chosen any other values of $\theta$ here as they would be outside my range. However the book I am working from says that:

$\theta = \pm 0.421$

I don't see how this can be true as sin is an even function. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong or what I'm misunderstanding?

Thank you :D

Comment: $1-6\sin^2\theta=0\iff |\sin\theta| =1/\sqrt6$. (More generally, $\sqrt{ x^2}=|x|$.)

Comment: By the way, $\sin$ is an odd function, not an even function.

Comment: Ahh, of course, thank you! I should have spotted that :P

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, sin is an odd function, sorry. Another silly mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by "parallel to the initial line"? (You found the $\theta$ values where the tangent lines are horizontal.)

Comment: I don't know whether this is convention or not, but my textbook, when working with polar coordinates, refers to the x-axis($\theta = 0$) as the "initial line".

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As  David Mitra pointed out in the comment below the question:

"$1−6sin^2 θ=0⟺|sinθ|=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \space$ (More generally, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$)"